# search with find command until first match

Tags: bash, command, find

I just need to search for a specific directory that can be anywhere is there a way to run this command until the first match? Thanx!
Im now ussing

```
find / -noleaf -name 'experiment' -type d | wc -l
```

Comment: consult the man page of find; it is the `-quit` option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rudolf Mühlbauer mentions, the `-quit` option tells `find` to quit.  The man page example is that
`find /tmp/foo /tmp/bar -print -quit`
will print only `/tmp/foo`.

Slightly more generally, `find` may be the wrong tool for what you want to do.  See `man locate`.  For example, on my system,
`locate experiment | head -3`
produces

```
/usr/lib/tc/experimental.dist
/usr/share/doc/xorg/reference/experimental.html
/usr/share/doc/xorg/reference/experimental.txt
```

while `locate -r 'experimental..$'` produces (with 6 lines snipped for brevity)

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic/include/config/experimental.h
 (snip)
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-32-generic/include/config/experimental.h
```

As noted in ShpielMeister's comment, the `locate` database is updated only periodically (eg, daily on Ubuntu Linux systems).  When new files are a concern, say `sudo updatedb`, which in a second or two of work will update the database.  Also see: [ioflood.com blog about locate command](https://ioflood.com/blog/locate-linux-command)

Comment: `The locate program searches a database for all pathnames which match the specified pattern.  The data-base is recomputed periodically (usually weekly or daily), and contains the pathnames of all files  which are publicly accessible.`

While `locate` may be useful in many situations, `find`importantly does NOT depend on a database, which may be stale.

Comment: @ShpielMeister, I added a note to answer